# Debugging Dapper Contrib (or any ORM) - how to see the generated SQL in Visual Studio - eg for update?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, dapper

I am getting a SQL Update error when trying to update a table by passing in an object to Dapper Contrib (I'm allowing it to map the object's properties to the database table):

```
connection.Update(myObject);
```

Without running some kind of SQL Server profiling tool, can I see the generated SQL within Visual Studio debugger - or expose it somehow? This would greatly increase the speed of debugging.

I have found pieces about running MiniProfiler - I can get it working but it's only giving me the speed of something - not SQL - I went far into the weeds on that and I'm not even sure it's the right approach.

What's the best / simplest / quickest approach here just to see what SQL is being generated & to debug it?

thx.

Comment: To get mini-profiler working here, wrap your connection in a `ProfiledDbConnection`, and pass that to the ORM

Comment: Ive done that - it's not showing me SQL though?

Comment: How are you viewing? Is this in-browser? Or?

Comment: Was in browser thx yes. However - I just realised 2 things - SQL Profiler is now included in Express 2014 - (other free tools also exist but I actually had it installed) and it's super easy to do it that way so that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ended up using SQL Profiler built into SQL Server. Simple easy solution.